# sidenav bar with dropdowns that open to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a side nav bar that's on the left side of my page.  Within that nav bar, I have a couple dropdown menus that I would like to open to the right instead of below.  I've read of using `data-toggle="popover"`, but is there a way using dropdowns instead?

thanks

Comment: add a sample code...of create jsfiddle for it...

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear as there is no code but according your description add the below list inside your dropdownlist  below one is in bootstrap

```
<ul class="nav  nav-stacked">
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Menu 
                <i class="icon icon-caret-right"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

see the below fiddle 
[demoFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdtsyraw/2/)

And if You only want to html css then 
try the below fiddle  hope it helps.

[csshtml dropdown fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYUeX/634/)

Comment: We have no real indication the OP is using Bootstrap. You should ateast indcate that your answer relies **heavily** upon it.

Comment: thank you  for your suggestion i also added for html css dropdown.